# Symfony2: check-email after registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

First time I'm posting a message in this forum, which I use regularly. I use FOSUserbundle in my Symfony2 application to manage users. I activated the sending of the email confirmation when users create an account by the following thing:

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
```

It works very well: the email is sent successfully. I am redirected to the page /check-email that says that this email has been sent. However, I would like to change the redirection : I would like to be redirected to my index page and not to /check-email. So I did my research and I knew he had to go through the FOSUserBundle events ([list here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php)).

What I did :

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

private $router;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
    $this->router = $router;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm');
}

public function onRegistrationConfirm(FormEvent $event) {
    $url = $this->router->generate('listeArticlesAccueil');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

}

and services.yml

```
services: 
    listener_user.registration_listener:
        class: My\Soft\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

The problem is that every time I am redirected to the page /check-email. I therefore told me that it was probably the wrong event. So I also tried REGISTRATION_SUCCESS. But nothing changes. So either I have not used the right event, or I'm doing something wrong.

In either case, I hope you can help me !

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question has been posted a long time ago, but i found a solution and I would like to share it to others that have the same issue.

In this case, the event that you should use is REGISTRATION_SUCCESS.

You have to prioritize the listener REGISTRATION_SUCCESS to be called before FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener::onRegistrationSuccess like this:

```
 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
 {
     return [
         FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
             ['onRegistrationSuccess', -10],
         ],
     ];
 }
```

If you don't do it, EmailConfirmationListener will be called earlier and you will be redirected to fos_user_registration_check_email route.

Here is what I did:

```
 class RedirectAfterRegistrationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
 {
private $router;

public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
{
    $event->stopPropagation();
    $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => ['onRegistrationSuccess',-10],
    ];
}
 }
```

And in app/services.yml:

```
app.redirect_after_registration_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\RedirectAfterRegistrationSubscriber
    arguments: ['@router']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet on REGISTRATION_SUCCESS. 
The doc (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php) says 
that this event allows to set the response.
REGISTRATION_CONFIRM only allows to access the user

Comment: You're right ! I tried with REGISTRATION_SUCCESS. When I don't active the email confirmation, I'm correctly redirected to my page. But when I activate the confirmation (with the file config.yml) I'm redirected to /check-email... I don't know why !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that use `REGISTRATION_CONFIRM`.

Here is the complete code for the event listener:

```
/**
 * Description of RegisterationConfirmListener
 *
 * @author imran
 */
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Description of RegisterationConfirmListener
 *
 * @author imran
 */
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener responsible to change the redirection at the end of the password resetting
 */
class RegisterationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegisterationConfirm',
        ];
    }

    public function onRegisterationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('home');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

For `Services.yml`:

```
app_user.registeration_confirmed:
    class: Wishlocker\AppBundle\EventListener\RegisterationConfirmListener
    arguments: [ @router ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```